# Why does my very basic Python file give an import error?

Tags: python, import, module, assert

I am experimenting with using assert testing but it seems like importing modules isn't working for my code unless I do it a very specific, but seemingly identical (in terms of what it actually does) way.

I have one file named gz.py, which has the following lines of code:

```
def sumnum(a,b):
    return a+b
```

I also have a file named test_x.py, which has the following lines of code:

```
import pytest
from gz import sumnum

def test_sumnum():
    assert sumnum(5,6) == 11,'wrong'
```

which gives an error, ImportError: cannot import name 'sumnum' from 'gz'. But it doesn't give this error if I import the entire module directly (i.e. import gz, and then assert gz.sumnum(5,6) == 11,'wrong'). Am I doing something wrong? All other posts I've seen have been due to circular import reasons, but I don't think that's an issue here, is it? In addition, do these two methods of importing not do the same thing? Why does one throw an error and not the other? Thanks

Edit: Solved. Always remember to save your changes before attempting to run them...

Comment: It works pretty fine for me. Could you update the tree of your directory, maybe that could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `test_sumnum()` function in `test_x.py` seems to work. I have updated the script to

```
import pytest
from gz import sumnum

def test_sumnum():
    assert sumnum(5,5) == 11,'wrong'
test_sumnum()

#Output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_x.py", line 6, in <module>
    test_sumnum()
  File "test_x.py", line 5, in test_sumnum
    assert sumnum(5,5) == 11,'wrong'
AssertionError: wrong
```